# css styles just stopped applying

Tags: css, coda

I am learning html and css and am using Coda.  I was doing great until I ran into a roadblock with my css.  After closing Coda yesterday, and re-opening it today, any css changes are not being applied.  The page is will show the style updates in coda, but once I save and the page reloads, it's right back to the css styles from yesterday.  I manually checked the files on the server and they are correct.  Any Ideas what's going on?

Comment: Impossible to say... could be your cache

Comment: If it's not a syntax or file path problem, it is impossible to tell without more information.